# Local development experience when working with microservices

Tags: microservices, local

What is the recommended local development/debugging approach for a microservice architecture?

We're coming from a monolithic web api where debugging involves attaching a debugger to a single process. Another process runs a SPA that calls into the API for back-end services. We run the SPA locally which calls the API locally and have full visibility into calls. Can this wholly local approach be applied to a microservices architecture where you may have 100 independent services glued together via API Gateway? If not, how do you run end to end development/debug cycles locally?

Comment: "Another process runs a SPA that calls into the API for back-end services." - by "SPA" do you mean "single-page application"? If so, why aren't you using an Integration test suite to make API calls or a utility like Postman?

Comment: Yes I do mean that. The situation I'm referring to is when you're reproducing a defect locally and have repro steps from QA, not raw HTTP req/resp details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local, "end to end" development, we use test doubles like http://wiremock.org/ to simulate the services that the SPA is dependent on. But they only emulates the final aggregated Web API and not the individual services that the API Gateway is gluing together.

We did consider using K8S and Helm charts to spin up the required containers for local debugging, but the capacity of the local machine soon became a bottleneck when spinning up a large number of services and databases.